# Magento 2.2.6 Checkout issue

Tags: magento2.2.6, authorize.net

I am using Magento 2.2.6 and I have some issue on checkout.
we are using auth.net direct post with the recent patch applied.
Initially it did work fine but since last two day we keep getting this error https://www.screencast.com/t/F6AsugPcDUi6. I debug a lot and found that when I keep Payment Mode Authorize and Capture , it is giving me this error . If I change it to Authorize only ,it allows to place order successfully.  When I check exception log it shows following error

```
[2019-03-16 19:22:53] main.CRITICAL: Invalid amount for capture. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): Invalid amount for capture. at html/vendor/magento/module-authorizenet/Model/Directpost.php:262)"} []
```

Has any one face similar issue ? Can this be related to recent auth.net patch ?

Other issue is sometimes the checkout page keeps loading forever. Hosting company found it might be related to google analytics script and use might have blocks ads , I am not sure if this is the case for all customer who face this issue . Has anyone found similar issue ?